# Why there is no tooltip for users-page answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, profile-page, tooltips

My user page has list of question asked by me and answers given by me..... I can see a tooltip of a question when i hover over the question link but i cant see a tooltip of my answer when i hover over an answer....

Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Maybe add some HTML to explain? For a question: `<a href="/questions/2415253/is-there-any-firefox-addon-to-find-asp-net-page-viewstate-size" class="question-hyperlink" title="Is there any firefox addon which can display my asp.net page viewstate size.... Any suggestion...">Is there any Firefox Addon to find ASP.NET page viewstate size?</a>` ...

Comment: ...and for an answer: `<a href="/questions/2362181/result-of-the-sum/2362268#2362268" class="answer-hyperlink">result of the sum</a>`

Comment: Hence: why no `title` attribute for answers, like present for questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the question titles of those you answered?

Well, I would think that because there are more focus on your own questions. Hence they are displayed with larger font size, vote/answer/view counts,and of course the tooltip.

Comment: Why "of course the tooltip"?

Comment: @Arjen, you can ignore the 'of course'. I mentioned it because it is already there, that's all.